# EF in .NET 3.5 insert child rows in wrong order

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-3.5

I use Entity Framework in my ASP.NET application (.NET 3.5)
My model is simple:

```
Order (Id)
Product (Id, OrderId)
Category (Id, ProductId, NameA, NameB)
```

My code looks like:

```
StoreEntity db = new StoreEntity(); 
Order order = GetOrder(1);
Product product = new Product();
product.Categories.Add(new Category() { NameA = "1" });
product.Categories.Add(new Category() { NameA = "2" });
product.Categories.Add(new Category() { NameA = "3" });
product.Categories.Add(new Category() { NameB = "A" });
product.Categories.Add(new Category() { NameB = "B" });
product.Categories.Add(new Category() { NameB = "C" });
order.Products.Add(product);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Problem is that in database categories are in wrong order, that is:

```
CategoryId,ProductId,NameA,NameB
1,1,3,NULL
2,1,2,NULL
3,1,1,NULL
4,1,NULL,C
5,1,NULL,B
6,1,NULL,A
```

When I switch to .NET 4 row order is correct. Is there a way to fix this in 3.5 ?

Comment: Relational Databases are Set based systems. There is no concept of order unless you specifically enforce one artificially such as an ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know no EF version will ensure that items will be inserted in the same order as created in the application. If it works in EFv4 it will be most probably just luck because I have many examples where order is different in EFv4 as well.

Comment: I noticed that order is not reversed - its random